# Is there a universal function F that F(sha(a),sha(b)) = sha(ab)

Tags: math, hash, sha

I am faced with a need to send my data in parts, and at the same time I am expected to provide sha256 for my WHOLE data.

Something like this `cat large file | chunker | receiver`
where receiver is an application that is expected to receive the data, possibly in chunks having in the header sha256 of the payload, and then following payload. After collecting all chunks, it is supposed to store the whole transmitted data, and the sha256 of all data (particular sha256 will be used only to rehash and confirm integrity of the data.)

Of course, the simplest thing would be if the receiver generated sha256 from whole the streamed data, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way by collecting all hashes of all chunks, and combine them to generate one final hash, which would be the same as the hash calculated from all the data.

In other words - and I copy this from the title - I wonder if there is a function F that would receive a list of hashes of chunks of data, and then generated final hash that would be equal to the hash generated on all the data.

And again, in other words, having this formula:
F(sha256(data[0]), sha256(data[1]), ... sha256(data[N])) = sha256(data[0..N])

What would be the function F?
Would it be a universal function or there is no such thing for the way hashing is calculated?

I suspect there is no such function or this is too complicated question to answer.

Comment: The result of a hash operation does not include enough information to continue the hash operation, which includes all the state information within the hash algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are still no known collisions for SHA-256 but I bet that once some is found, i.e. someone finds two messages `m1` and `m2` such that `SHA-256(m1) = SHA-256(m2)`, then for almost any prefix `a` hashes `SHA-256(a || m1)` and `SHA-256(a || m2)` will be different i.e. the function you ask is actually not a function (has different outputs for the same inputs). Or to put it otherwise SHA-2 is susceptible to length extension attacks but AFAIK not to prefixing attacks. Still even if this actually a function, it is not enough for you for such a function to exist, you also want it to be fast. And I believe there is no such fast to compute function.

On the other hand SHA-256 works by splitting the original message into 512-bit chunks and processing them using a well defined process (which is based on the state from all the previous chunks) so theoretically you can modify some implementation of `SHA-256` to compute two hashes at the same time (by applying the same logic to different initial states):

1. Hash of your application-defined chunk (using standard initial state)
2. Hash of all chunks up to this point (using the state passed from the previous output of the same step as the initial state).

This probably will be slightly faster than doing those things independently but I don't know whether it will be so much faster to justify such a custom implementation.

Comment: All crypto libraries I know of already provide an API that does 'init/setup, process one or more (any number of) chunks of input, finish/cleanup' for both hashes and (bulk/symmetric) ciphers

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I don't see how this can result in any speed up comparing to the just running SHA-256 independently on the whole piece of data. The only (little) chance I see is to process every chunk two times simultaneously so it will be a little more efficient in terms of memory access.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - from the comments I read, this process would not end up with a hash equal to a hash made from the whole data. Am I right?

Comment: @Grzegorz, which exactly process do you mean? From some high-level what SHA-2 does can be described as a repetition of two steps for each chunk 1. Using some initial state to mangle a chunk of the data 2. Using the mangled chunk to update the state. There is also some default value for initial state (i.e. before first chunk). There is nothing that forces you to process all chunks in the same run. You can save current state and use it as new initial state (instead of default) for next batch of chunks and the result will be the same as if you processed both batches as a whole.

Comment: But if for each batch of chunks you started from the default initial state, there is no easy way to merge those hashes into proper output for the whole data and actually I bet it is impossible to do the merge because it is not a deterministic result.